# Sort A list of Strings Based on certain field

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

Overview: I have data something like this (each row is a string):

> 81:0A:D7:19:25:7B, **2016-07-14 14:29:13**, 2016-07-14 14:29:15, -69, 22:22:22:22:22:23,null,^M
> 3B:3F:B9:0A:83:E6, **2016-07-14 01:28:59**, 2016-07-14 01:29:01, -36, 33:33:33:33:33:31,null,^M
> B3:C0:6E:77:E5:31, **2016-07-14 08:26:45**, 2016-07-14 08:26:47, -65, 33:33:33:33:33:32,null,^M
> 61:01:55:16:B5:52, **2016-07-14 06:25:32**, 2016-07-14 06:25:34, -56, 33:33:33:33:33:33,null,^M

And I want to sort each row based on the first timestamp that is present in the each String, which for these four records is:

> 2016-07-14 01:28:59
>
> 2016-07-14 06:25:32
>
> 2016-07-14 08:26:45
>
> 2016-07-14 14:29:13

Now I know the `sort()` method but I don't understand how can I use here to sort all the rows based on this (timestamp) quantity, and I do need to keep the final sorted data in the same format as some other service is going to use it.

I also understand I can make the `key()` but I am not clear how that can be made to sort on the timestamp field.

Comment: Is the formatting always the same? Do you know that the first timestamp always is second (after the first comma)?

Comment: Yes, it is always the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the list method `list.sort` which sorts in-place or use the `sorted()` built-in function which returns a new list. the `key` argument takes a function which it applies to each element of the sequence before sorting. You can use a combination of `string.split(',')` and indexing to the second element, e.g. some_list[1], so:

```
In [8]: list_of_strings
Out[8]: 
['81:0A:D7:19:25:7B, 2016-07-14 14:29:13, 2016-07-14 14:29:15, -69, 22:22:22:22:22:23,null,^M',
 '3B:3F:B9:0A:83:E6, 2016-07-14 01:28:59, 2016-07-14 01:29:01, -36, 33:33:33:33:33:31,null,^M',
 'B3:C0:6E:77:E5:31, 2016-07-14 08:26:45, 2016-07-14 08:26:47, -65, 33:33:33:33:33:32,null,^M',
 '61:01:55:16:B5:52, 2016-07-14 06:25:32, 2016-07-14 06:25:34, -56, 33:33:33:33:33:33,null,^M']

In [9]: sorted(list_of_strings, key=lambda s: s.split(',')[1])
Out[9]: 
['3B:3F:B9:0A:83:E6, 2016-07-14 01:28:59, 2016-07-14 01:29:01, -36, 33:33:33:33:33:31,null,^M',
 '61:01:55:16:B5:52, 2016-07-14 06:25:32, 2016-07-14 06:25:34, -56, 33:33:33:33:33:33,null,^M',
 'B3:C0:6E:77:E5:31, 2016-07-14 08:26:45, 2016-07-14 08:26:47, -65, 33:33:33:33:33:32,null,^M',
 '81:0A:D7:19:25:7B, 2016-07-14 14:29:13, 2016-07-14 14:29:15, -69, 22:22:22:22:22:23,null,^M']
```

Or if you'd rather sort a list in place,

```
list_of_strings
Out[12]: 
['81:0A:D7:19:25:7B, 2016-07-14 14:29:13, 2016-07-14 14:29:15, -69, 22:22:22:22:22:23,null,^M',
 '3B:3F:B9:0A:83:E6, 2016-07-14 01:28:59, 2016-07-14 01:29:01, -36, 33:33:33:33:33:31,null,^M',
 'B3:C0:6E:77:E5:31, 2016-07-14 08:26:45, 2016-07-14 08:26:47, -65, 33:33:33:33:33:32,null,^M',
 '61:01:55:16:B5:52, 2016-07-14 06:25:32, 2016-07-14 06:25:34, -56, 33:33:33:33:33:33,null,^M']

list_of_strings.sort(key=lambda s: s.split(',')[1])

list_of_strings
Out[14]: 
['3B:3F:B9:0A:83:E6, 2016-07-14 01:28:59, 2016-07-14 01:29:01, -36, 33:33:33:33:33:31,null,^M',
 '61:01:55:16:B5:52, 2016-07-14 06:25:32, 2016-07-14 06:25:34, -56, 33:33:33:33:33:33,null,^M',
 'B3:C0:6E:77:E5:31, 2016-07-14 08:26:45, 2016-07-14 08:26:47, -65, 33:33:33:33:33:32,null,^M',
 '81:0A:D7:19:25:7B, 2016-07-14 14:29:13, 2016-07-14 14:29:15, -69, 22:22:22:22:22:23,null,^M']
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format of the line in itself shall not be changed, maybe (I do not know the wider context of the solution) a simple shell transformation is fitting well (I know it is not a python solution).

So:

```
$ sort -t, -k2,2 sort_me_on_first_timestamp_field.txt 
3B:3F:B9:0A:83:E6, 2016-07-14 01:28:59, 2016-07-14 01:29:01, -36, 33:33:33:33:33:31,null,^M 
61:01:55:16:B5:52, 2016-07-14 06:25:32, 2016-07-14 06:25:34, -56, 33:33:33:33:33:33,null,^M
B3:C0:6E:77:E5:31, 2016-07-14 08:26:45, 2016-07-14 08:26:47, -65, 33:33:33:33:33:32,null,^M 
81:0A:D7:19:25:7B, 2016-07-14 14:29:13, 2016-07-14 14:29:15, -69, 22:22:22:22:22:23,null,^M
```

Looks quite OK to me. the -t option tells sort to use the comma as the delimiter, the -k2,2 requests sorting based on the second "field" (it starts counting at one). sometimes it is important to switch with -n to numerical sorting, but here with ISO datetime string of fixed length it should work with lexical sorting.

Again: If you are looking for a pure python solution, I suggest picking the suggested python based answer. This here only suggests a baseline alternative.

**Update** to "measure" some scenario on some machine - well:

On the "machine of the developer", sorting the sample 4 lines concatenated multiple times into files of 20, 200, 2000, ..., 2,000,000 lines take from 12 milli seconds to 1.7 seconds (for 2 million lines) to sort with the sort command writing to /dev/null and 2 seconds writing to a file.

A naive implementation of @juanpa.arrivillaga's proposed route sorting in-place:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
FILE_PATH_IN = './fhf.txt'
NL, FS = '\n', ','

list_of_strings = open(FILE_PATH_IN).read().split(NL)[:-1]
list_of_strings.sort(key=lambda s: s.split(FS)[1])
with open(FILE_PATH_IN + ".out", "wt") as f:
    f.write(NL.join(list_of_strings))
```

on the same machine takes approx. 3 seconds for the 2 million line case as the other variant (using sorted to generate a new list) does:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
FILE_PATH_IN = './fhf.txt'
NL, FS = '\n', ','

list_of_strings = open(FILE_PATH_IN).read().split(NL)[:-1]
with open(FILE_PATH_IN + ".out", "wt") as f:
    f.write(NL.join(sorted(list_of_strings, key=lambda s: s.split(',')[1])))
```

So suggested is, to use the pure python solution.

Comment: So since both shell and python can be used to achieve the task, it takes me to the next question: If I have a file with such 20,00,000 records which approach is better: 1. Reading the file in python program->putting all records in a list->sort the list-> put the sorted list to new file 
Or
sorting the file using shell??
please suggest

Comment: 2 million lines is not much to keep in memory these days - so both ways should be good enough for most purposes. When rare defects creep into the data (truncated lines etc.) the python solution might offer a better tool set to clean the incoming data, and if the reader and writer do not slow down that would be good. But you can always measure (as the shell command is simply there), and decide based on that. Note the python proposed solution already sorts in place, so you do not generate multiple copies with it either.

Comment: Yes and If i use shell it will write to a new file. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: In shell lingo all is open for "plumbing", like `cat fhf.txt | sort -t, -k2,2 > out_file.txt` where instead of the `cat fhf.txt` part some source process might directly write the incoming data to a pipe, where sort reads from and then either pipes into a subsequent consumer of the sorted data or like here writes to an out file.

Comment: (Y) for the time calculation insight

Answer (score 1):

you can use `string.split()`，string.split(',')[1]